# Not able to connect to remote database through ssh tunneling in python

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to connect to a remote database through ssh tunneling. But I am getting an error when I try to connect. Below is my code and the error

```
def query(q):
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
            ("bastion.example.co", 22),
            ssh_username="ubuntu",
            ssh_pkey="~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
            remote_bind_address=("127.0.0.1", 3306)
    ) as server:
        conn = mysql.connect(host="xyz.rds.amazonaws.com",
                          port=server.local_bind_port,
                          user="prod_db",
                          passwd="123abc",
                          db="prod_db")
        return pd.read_sql_query(q, conn)

print(query('select * from abc_table'))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conn_mysql.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(query('select * from abc_table'))
  File "conn_mysql.py", line 11, in query
    remote_bind_address=("127.0.0.1", 3306)
  File "/Users/mohnishmallya/PycharmProjects/3Bvs2A/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 904, in __init__
    logger=self.logger
  File "/Users/mohnishmallya/PycharmProjects/3Bvs2A/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1095, in _consolidate_auth
    raise ValueError('No password or public key available!')
ValueError: No password or public key available!
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh_pkey` parameter of [`SSHTunnelForwarder` constructor](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder) to provide the path to your *private* key file (not the public key `.pub`).